# How do I count across a date range in an R datatable

Tags: r, count, data.table, date-range

```
ID      FROM        TO
1881    11/02/2013  11/02/2013
3090    09/09/2013  09/09/2013
1113    24/11/2014  06/12/2014
1110    24/07/2013  25/07/2013
111     25/06/2015  05/09/2015
```

If I have data.table of vacation dates, FROM and TO, I want to know how many people were on vacation for any given month.

I tried:

```
dt[, .N, by=.(year(FROM), month(FROM))]
```

but obviously it would exclude people who were on vacation across two months.  ie. someone on vacation FROM JAN TO FEB would only show up in the JAN count and not the FEB count even though they are still on vacation in FEB

The output of the above code showing year, month and number is exactly what I'm looking for otherwise.

```
    year month N
 1: 2013     2 17570
 2: 2013     9 16924
 3: 2014    11 18809
 4: 2013     7 16984
 5: 2015     6 14401
 6: 2015    12 10239
 7: 2014     3 19346
 8: 2013     5 14864
```

EDIT:  I want every month someone is away on vacation counted.  So ID 111 would be counted in June, July, August and Sept.

EDIT 2:

Running uwe's code on the full dataset produces the Total Count column below.
Subsetting the full data set for people on vacation for <= 30 days  and > 30 days produces the counts in the respective columns below.  These columns added to each other should equal the Total Count and therefore the DIFFERENCE should be 0 but this isn't the case.

`month       Total count   <=30    >30   (<=30) + (>30)    DIFFERENCE
01/02/2012    899           4     895         899            0
01/03/2012    3966       2320    1646        3966            0
01/04/2012    8684       6637    2086        8723           39
01/05/2012    10287      7586    2750        10336          49
01/06/2012    12018      9080    3000        12080          62`

Comment: Use `melt` to combine `FROM` and `TO` then group by.

Comment: How do you want to count ID 111? Only in June 2015 and in September 2015? Or in June, July, August, and September 2015?

Comment: I want to count June, July, August and September 2015.  I am trying to figure out the number of people who went on vacation in any given month.  ID 111 was away in June, July, August and September 2015 so will be counted for each month.

Comment: is the above result what you expect from the data you gave?

Comment: I agree with Uwe's suggestion -- better to post a new question (with reproducible data) unless he somehow recognizes the root issue and offers a quick fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has not specified what the exact rules are for counting, for instance, how to count if the same ID has multiple non-overlapping periods of vacation in the same month.

The solution below is based on the following rules:

1. Each `ID` may appear in more than one row.
2. For each row, the total number of month between `FROM` and `TO` are counted (including the `FROM` and `TO` months). E.g., `ID` 111 is counted in the months of June, July, August, and September 2015.
3. Vacation on the last and first day of a month are accounted in full, e.g., vacations starting on May 31 and ending on June 1, are counted in both months.
4. If an `ID` has multiple periods of vacation in one month it is only counted once.

To verify that the code implements these rule, I had to enhance the sample dataset provided by the OP with additional use cases (see **Data** section below)

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
# coerce dt to data.table object and character dates to class Date
setDT(dt)[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, dmy), .SDcols = 2:3]

# for each row, create sequence of first days of months 
dt[, .(month = seq(floor_date(FROM, "months"), TO, by = "months")), by = .(ID, rowid(ID))][
  # count the number of unique IDs per month, order result by month
  , uniqueN(ID), keyby = month]
```

> ```
>          month V1
>  1: 2013-02-01  1
>  2: 2013-07-01  1
>  3: 2013-09-01  2
>  4: 2014-11-01  1
>  5: 2014-12-01  1
>  6: 2015-06-01  1
>  7: 2015-07-01  1
>  8: 2015-08-01  1
>  9: 2015-09-01  1
> 10: 2015-11-01  1
> 11: 2015-12-01  1
> 12: 2016-06-01  1
> 13: 2016-07-01  1
> 14: 2016-08-01  1
> 15: 2016-09-01  1
> ```

#### Data

Based on OP's sample dataset but extended by additional use cases:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(
  "ID      FROM        TO
1881    11/02/2013  11/02/2013
1881    23/02/2013  24/02/2013
3090    09/09/2013  09/09/2013
3091    09/09/2013  09/09/2013
1113    24/11/2014  06/12/2014
1110    24/07/2013  25/07/2013
111     25/06/2015  05/09/2015
111     25/11/2015  05/12/2015
11      25/06/2016  01/09/2016"
)
```

Comment: Many thanks for this.  The rules you applied are exactly what I was looking for.  Now I have unpack it and swot up on how it all works!

Comment: I am glad that this seems to work for you. I was not sure if my interpretation of the rules on how to count the vacations per month will meet your requirements.

Comment: I think  there might be a problem.  I tried running this code on the entire datase.  I then subsetted the entire dataset into two datatables, on for people on vacation for 30 days or more and another for people on vacation for less than 30 days.  Running the code again on the two different datatables produces a different total count.

Comment: What kind of problem?

Comment: {month Total count <=30 > 30 (<=30) + (>30) DIFFERENCE
01/02/2012 899 4 895 899 0
01/03/2012 3966 2320 1646 3966 0
01/04/2012 8684 6637 2086 8723 39
01/05/2012 10287 7586 2750 10336 49
01/06/2012 12018 9080 3000 12080 62}

Comment: Not sure if you can read the table above.  It should be 6 rows.  DIFFERENCE should be 0.  The Total Count should equal (<=30) + (>30).  I can't seem to create a code block in comments.  I will try to figure it out and re comment later.

Comment: No worries about the formatting. I was able to read the table. What puzzles me are the differences. Perhaps, it would be best if you would post a new question including the code for subsetting and summarising. Also, formatting is easier than in comment :-)

Comment: On further investigation, this code doesn't work.  From the subset of people on vacation 30 days or less, I subsetted all the FROM and TO dates which contains a 2012 - 04 value.  This subset would miss out people who were away from 2012 - 03 to 2012 - 05 for instance and was small enough to allow me to eyeball the figures.  Yet it was LARGER (8863) than the total count on the WHOLE dataset (8684) created by uwe's code for that month.  Thanks for trying anyway uwe.

Comment: could the UniqueN be a problem?  The same employee might be away more than two or three times a month.

Comment: It's not a problem but it's according to the specifications, rule 4 that a person on vacation is only counted once per month regardless of how many times the person is absent.

Comment: Ah you are right.  Sorry, need to reboot my brain after Easter break.  Too  many chocolate eggs.

Answer (score 0):

for the data given above, you will do:

```
melt(dat,1)[,value:=as.Date(sub("\\d+","20",value),"%d/%m/%Y")][,
         seq(value[1],value[2],by="1 month"),by=ID][,.N,by=.(year(V1),month(V1))]
   year month N
1: 2013     2 1
2: 2013     9 1
3: 2014    11 1
4: 2014    12 1
5: 2013     7 1
6: 2015     6 1
7: 2015     7 1
8: 2015     8 1
9: 2015     9 1
```

Comment: I am not sure  if this is the correct result because there are no counts for July 2015 and August 2015 (see `ID` 111). I have asked OP for clarification.

Comment: I see what you mean

Comment: There is another issue: Does the OP really wants to have ID's 1881, 3090, and 1110 counted twice?

Comment: Nice, both approaches use `seq()` but there are differences in handling multiple rows with the same `ID`. Still the OP has to clarify if this may happen in his production dataset.